# Check DataTable rows for duplicate values and their count

Tags: c#, datatable, expression

I have a C# DataTable that has 3 columns. The columns/cells will contain an ascii character, the columns are used as a store for these characters and so are unnamed.

I'm trying to figure out how to count how many times a given character occurs in each row.

I need to count the occurrences of, say, the character 'x' in each row.

At first I thought about the `DataTable.Select` method, however not only could I not figure out a proper expression but upon further reading I think `DataTable.Compute` might be a better fit.

I've seen the MSDN examples but they all sum all values in a column, I haven't found anything about counting all values in a row.

An example.

Imagine my table is like this:

```
r j k
x f x
p p o
```

I would like to know how many times each character in the table appears in each row, so for this case:

r, j, k - once in row0
x - twice in row1
f - once in row1
p - twice in row2
o - once in row2

Answer (score 1):

You can execute a `Linq` query to [flatten](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany%2560%25602)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) and [group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.GroupBy%2560%25602)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) the [`DataRow.ItemArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.itemarray?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Data.DataRow.ItemArray)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) values. Then you can select from the `IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, object>>` the `Key` and `Count` of each element, the field's value and its duplicates in the `ItemArray` respectively.

Assuming you have a `DataTable` like...

```cs
var dt = new DataTable()

dt.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("col3", typeof(string));

dt.Rows.Add("r", "j", "k");
dt.Rows.Add("x", "f", "x");
dt.Rows.Add("p", "p", "o");
```

In some caller...

```cs
var q = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .SelectMany((r, i) => r.ItemArray
    .GroupBy(g => g)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        RowIndex = i,
        Value = x.Key.ToString(),
        Count = x.Count()
    }));

foreach (var item in q) Console.WriteLine(item);
```

`q` here is `IEnumerable` of anonymous type. You can replace it with a model/record to get/return `IEnumerable<T>`.

```cs
public class SomeModel
{
    public int RowIndex { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Value}, RowIndex: {RowIndex}, Count: {Count}";
    }
}
```

and select `new SomeModel` in the query:

```cs
var q = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .SelectMany((r, i) => r.ItemArray
    .GroupBy(g => g)
    .Select(x => new SomeModel
    {
        RowIndex = i,
        Value = x.Key.ToString(),
        Count = x.Count()
    }));

foreach (var item in q) Console.WriteLine(item);
```

The output:

```
r, RowIndex: 0, Count: 1
j, RowIndex: 0, Count: 1
k, RowIndex: 0, Count: 1
x, RowIndex: 1, Count: 2
f, RowIndex: 1, Count: 1
p, RowIndex: 2, Count: 2
o, RowIndex: 2, Count: 1
```